# Is it random and representative of all Australians if 200 people are interviewed from the the Sydney area Phone book?

Tags: statistics

1000 people selected, 200 replies those were taken in as data. Is this representative of Australian even though it's just in the sydney area. Is it random?

Comment: I would say that this isn't really a mathematical question. What about the stats stackexchange site?

Comment: Soz i got confused i thought tagging was enough

Comment: It depends what questions they were asked. Also, how were the 200 replies selected?

Comment: @user156684  No worries! You will get better answers there, I think.

Comment: @user156684 You know the answer just by reading the title, and knowing what random sampling even means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. If you did such a study and claimed to have done a country-wide representative sample, yet only had people from one city, you would be committing rather gross overgeneralization, and the validity of any findings would be questioned if you attempted to extend them from being about Sydney folks to all Australians.

Of course, it is possible that Sydney is truly a microcosm of Australia...but unless you prove that first, then the study will be bogus.

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be moved over to Cross Validated, but it can merit an answer here.

1) In order for a sample to be representative of a population, the sample has to be selected from the entire population. So in this case, it is not representative of the entire Australian population. It is only representative of the population of Sydney that has a landline with a listed phone number. There may also be some bias introduced if some demographics are more likely to respond to a phone survey than others (since the situation seems to be that you called 1000 but only 200 responded), so to be really specific, we would say that it's representative of the population of Sydney that has a landline AND would respond to a phone survey if called. Many pollsters tend to ignore a lot of those qualifiers.

2) "Is it random" is simultaneously an easy and a hard question, because you don't specify how the names are chosen and we don't have a reference point. It's random with reference to people who have landlines (again, with the caveat that some people might be more likely to respond to phone surveys), but not random with respect to the population of Australia (or even of Sydney).

If you're just asking about the method of selecting the actual names from the book, then it could be random but I don't think that's what you mean.